# Sum of specific elements of a list based on indexes from another list in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, indexing, sum

I am trying to find the durations of all the notes with the same name in a music piece (from .xml), in python. I have 3 lists:

```
scales = ['A', 'B', 'C'] #scales names
notesAll = ['B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C']  #note names of the piece
durationsAll = [1, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1, 2]  #duration of each note from notesAll list
```

I want to sum all the durations from durationsAll list for all the notes with the same name. For example **for all** the 'A's from notesAll list, which equals to scales[0], I want something like: durationsAll[1] + durationsAll[3]= 1.5 + 1 = 2.5. I need a better solution than my attempt:

```
for sc in scales:
  for ntPosition, nt in enumerate(notesAll):
    dtOfEach = 0
    for dtPosition, dt in enumerate(durationsAll):
      if sc == nt:
        dtPosotion = ntPosition  #I guess here is the problem
        dtOfEach = dtOfEach + dt
```

The result I want would be: `dtOfEach: 2.5  1  4.5`

Comment: `1.5 + 1 = 3.5` surely, this is a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should the first sum be 2.5? If so something, like the code at the end of this message should work. I think you basically had it with using a for loop and then enumerate but I wasn't sure what the second enumerate was for.

Also you have a line that reads:

```
dtPosotion = ntPosition  #I guess here is the problem
```

Is dtPosotion a typo? Or are you trying to set dtPosition = ntPosition. If so I don't think that's possible because dtPosition and ntPosition are set by your enumerate loops.

```
scales = ['A', 'B', 'C'] #scales names
notesAll = ['B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C']  #notes names of the piece
durationsAll = [1, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1, 2]  #duration of each note from notesAll list
sums = [0,0,0]

for s in scales:
    print "Scale letter:" + str(s)
    for i,j in enumerate(notesAll):
        if j == s:
            sums[scales.index(s)] +=durationsAll[i]

print sums
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I wanted, you helped me a lot!

(I was trying to set dtPosition = ntPosition, but I knew this was wrong)

Answer (score 0):

defaultdict is perfect here (assuming note and note's duration are in corresponding lists of course)

```
from collections import defaultdict

duration_total = defaultdict(int)
for note in list(zip(notesAll, durationsAll)):
    duration_total[note[0]] += note[1]

print(duration_total)
```

> {'B': 1, 'A': 2.5, 'C': 4.5})

I think A:3.5 in your question was a typo ?

**EDIT**

Updated code with Chris' suggestion:

```
for note, duration in zip(notesAll, durationsAll):
    duration_total[note] += duration
```

Comment: Neater `for note, duration in zip(notesAll, durationsAll): duration_total[note] += duration`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, although I wanted to print out the durations in the order that notes appear in scales.
(Of course 3.5 was wrong, micalculated actually)

Answer (score 0):

You could use indices and proceed like this:

```
def get_total_duration(note):
    return sum(durationsAll[idx] for idx, nt in enumerate(notesAll) if nt == note)


scales = ['A', 'B', 'C'] #scales names
notesAll = ['B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C']  #note names of the piece
durationsAll = [1, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1, 2]

get_total_duration('A')
```

#### output:

```
2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do an indirect sort and then group using `groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby

scales = ['A', 'B', 'C'] #scales names
notesAll = ['B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C']  #note names of the piece
durationsAll = [1, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1, 2]  #duration of each note from notesAll list

# do indirect sort
idx = sorted(range(len(notesAll)), key=notesAll.__getitem__)
# group and sum
result = {k: sum(map(durationsAll.__getitem__, grp))
          for k, grp in groupby(idx, notesAll.__getitem__)}

# {'A': 2.5, 'B': 1, 'C': 4.5}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with a list comprehension, exploiting the idea that booleans behave like integers

---

```
In [3]: S = ['A', 'B', 'C'] #scales names
   ...: N = ['B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'C']  #note names of the piece
   ...: D = [1, 1.5, 1.5, 1, 1, 2]  #duration of each note from notesAll list
In [4]: [sum(match*d for match, d in zip((n==s for n in N), D)) for s in S]
Out[4]: [2.5, 1.0, 4.5]
```

---

If you need a dictionary

---

```
In [5]: {s:sum(match*d for match, d in zip((n==s for n in N), D)) for s in S}
Out[5]: {'A': 2.5, 'B': 1.0, 'C': 4.5}
```

or, avoiding one loop and w/o importing `collections`

```
In [6]: r = {}
In [7]: for n, d  in zip(N, D): r[n] = r.get(n, 0) + d
In [8]: r
Out[8]: {'A': 2.5, 'B': 1, 'C': 4.5}
```

where we access the data in the dictionary not  by indexing but using the dictionary `.get(key, default)` method that makes it possible to initialize correctly our values.